# Angular JS :How to capture the Selected value under Onchage

Tags: angularjs

On the drop down change  i am trying to capture the selected value .

This is my code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
   <table border="1">
      <tr>
         <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in collectioninfo[0]">
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key)>=0">
               <select ng-change="getchange()" >
                  <option>{{key}}</option>
                  <option ng-repeat="(k, v) in val[0]" value="{{v}}">{{k}}</option>
               </select>
            </span>
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key)<0">
            {{ key }}
            </span>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in collectioninfo">
         <td ng-repeat="(key2, val2) in row">
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key2)>=0">
            {{ getFirstKeyOfDropDown(val2) }}
            </span>
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key2)<0">
            {{ val2 }}
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

When i kept ng-change="getchange()"  , it is expecting ng-model and ng-model leads to empty headers

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sD7X9/28/

Could you please let me know how to get the selected value ??

Comment: do you need the `Domains` as header too

Comment: yes we need that ....

Comment: if you use ng-model, you can give the default value to set the dropdown selected right? is there any issue with that approach in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing is you can't use `ng-change` without `ng-model`. In order keep the select box value and avoid empty header, you can assign a value to `ng-model` using `ng-init`

```
<select ng-change="getchange(selectItem)" ng-model="selectItem" ng-init="selectItem = key">
    <option>{{key}}</option>
    <option ng-repeat="(k, v) in val[0]" value="{{v}}">{{k}}</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6atm89o/)

Comment: looks perfect what is needed , is it possible to get the key rather than value in the alert being displayed ?

Comment: @Kiran change the value= {{k}}   `<option ng-repeat="(k, v) in val[0]" value="{{k}}">{{k}}`

Answer (score 1):

Your `<select>` doesn't have an `ng-model` which is required (you'd knew had you seen your console errors).

```
<select ng-change="getchange(dropdownvalue)" ng-model="dropdownvalue">
  <option ng-selected="true">{{key}}</option>
  <option ng-repeat="(k, v) in val[0]" value="{{v}}">{{k}}</option>
</select>
```

And, in controller,

```
$scope.getchange = function(value) {
  alert(value)
}
```

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sD7X9/30/)

Comment: @Kiran you want `Domains` selected?